# WSO2ESB REST API receives Microsoft Excel Worksheet (.xlsx) from attachment and Generate doc type error

Tags: wso2-esb

I have created an REST API that accepts a Microsoft Excel Worksheet (.xlsx) file as POST input. Code is mentioned below:

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="classroomcourse"  context="/classroomcourse">
<resource methods="POST">
<inSequence>
 <log level="full"/>
 <property name="messageType" value="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" scope="axis2"/>
 <send>
    <endpoint>
       <http uri-template="http://qa-aaa.ggg.com/xyz/api/importCourses"/>
    </endpoint>
 </send>
</inSequence>
<outSequence>
 <log level="full"/>
 <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
 <send/>
</outSequence>
```

When I send request via POSTMAN and attach xlsx file using form-data then I get the below error on the ESB Console:

[2016-03-02 17:32:13,332] ERROR - Error while building Passthrough  stream {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils}  org.apache.axiom.om.OMException:  com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '"' (code     34) in DOCTYPE declaration; expected a space be tween public and system identifiers at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,50] at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:296) at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMDocumentImpl.getOMDocumentElement(OMDocumentImpl.java:109) at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.getDocumentElement(StAXOMBuilder.java:570) at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.getDocumentElement(StAXOMBuilder.java:566) at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.DeferredMessageBuilder.getDocument(DeferredMessageBuilder.java:149) at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.builldMessage(RelayUtils.java:133) at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:98) at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:72) at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:48) at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:149) at org.apache.synapse.rest.Resource.process(Resource.java:297).....................

Kindly guide me what i did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Set message builder correctly in the axis2.xml or remove the log mediator inside the inSequence.